# Use Unity to resolve current NHibernate session for injection into Repositories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, nhibernate, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have a multi-project MVC 5 solution, where NHibernate repositories are declared in a `Core.Data` class library, but my session management is in the Wen API `Core.Api` project. It creates and destroys a session per request:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    // start a session
    var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
    session.BeginTransaction();
}

public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    // commit the current session
    var session = SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
    var transaction = session.Transaction;
    if (transaction != null && transaction.IsActive)
    {
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
    session.Close();
}
```

Now when I instantiate a repository in a controller action,I would like this particular session to be injected into the repository. How can I achieve this? I can do a `BaseRepository<T>: IRepository<T>`, with a constructor that finds the session, but I would really much rather like it injected. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at Unity's PerRequestLifetimeManager? I've got what your asking for wired up in our project, and it's all based on the PerRequestLifetimeManager. I.e., register the session in the container with a lifetime of "request", and then resolve repositories/sessions as usual from unity - in effect getting a fresh session per request. I can post a more detailed answer later today.

Comment: Thank you, @aeliusd. I may need a tiny bit more detail. I've never used NHibernate at all before.

Answer (score 1):

This is a snippet from how we do it.

```
public class UnityConfig
{

    private static readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> _container = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        RegisterTypes(container);

        return container;
    });

    //easy access to the container from anywhere in the application
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        //uses the Resolve<T> extension method
        return GetConfiguredContainer().Resolve<T>();
    }

    private static void Register(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository>(
            new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISession>()));


        container.RegisterType<ISession>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionFactory(c =>
                c.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()
                ));

        container
            .RegisterType<ISessionFactory>(
                new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
                new InjectionFactory(c =>
                {
                    var v =
                        Fluently.Configure()
                            .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                                .ConnectionString(d => d.FromConnectionStringWithKey("web.config.connection.string.key"))
                                .ShowSql()
                                .Dialect<CustomOcMsSqlDialect>())
                            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<IRepository>()
                                .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<IRepository>())
                            .BuildSessionFactory();
                    return v;
                })
            );

    }

}

public interface IRepository
{
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public Repository(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
}

public class SomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        var repo = UnityConfig.Resolve<IRepository>();
        var dbEntity = repo.Load(123);
        return View("SomeView");
    }
}
```

We wire up the repository, the session and the session-factory through unity. The factory is set to `ContainerControlled`(unity singleton). The session is set to `PerRequest`, so we get a new session for each request. And the repository uses the regular lifetime-manager so we get a new one for each resolve.

This way you can ask unity for a repository and get the same session throughout the entire request. It will also dispose the session automatically at the end of the request. But I'm sure you could hook into the ApplicationEndRequest event and do some housecleaning as well if you wanted.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In your `SomeAction` you call `UnityConfig.Resolve<IRepository>()`, yet `UnityConfig` has no `Resolve` method. Then, would I create a singleton `IUnityContainer` on the app, the use that for `UnityConfig.Register` and wouldn't the `Resolve` method also require to be passed that same container?

Comment: Yea, sorry I omitted the static access and resolve methods I was using, edited them in now. The Resolve<T> is an extension method that comes with unity (it's in UnityContainerExtensions.cs in the Microsoft.Practices.Unity namespacce)